# How to resolve "runOnReady command exited with code 0" when restreaming a stream using Mediamtx?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm attempting to publish a stream to the RTMP port `1935` using a `ffmpeg` command with [Mediamtx](https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx) (v0.22.2). Afterward, I want to restream the mainstream to another path using the `runOnReady` command in the config file. However, I'm encountering an issue where `the runOnReady command exits with code 0.`

#### Steps to Replicate:

1. Use the provided docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

name: mediamtx
services:
  mediamtx:
    image: aler9/rtsp-simple-server:v0.22.2
    container_name: media_mtx_rtsp_server
    ports:
      - "8554:8554"
      - "1935:1935"
      - "8888:8888"
      - "8889:8889"
      - "9997:9997"
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./configs/mediamtx/config.yml:/mediamtx.yml
      - ../volumes/hls/segments:/hls/segments
```

2. Add the following path to the `config.yml` file:

```yaml
paths:
  show/test:
    runOnReady: ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/show/test -c copy -f flv "rtmp://localhost:1935/compressed/test"
    runOnReadyRestart: yes
```

3. Start the server using docker-compose.
4. Publish an `RTMP` stream to the server using the following command:

```bash
ffmpeg -re -stream_loop -1 -i files/sample-30s.mp4 -c copy -f flv "rtmp://localhost:1935/show/test"
```

5. When I check the logs:

```
2023/07/01 15:16:30 INF [RTMP] [conn 172.26.0.1:51044] opened
2023/07/01 15:16:30 INF [path show/test] runOnReady command started
2023/07/01 15:16:30 INF [RTMP] [conn 172.26.0.1:51044] is publishing to path 'show/test', 2 tracks (H264, MPEG4-audio-gen)
2023/07/01 15:16:30 INF [path show/test] runOnReady command exited with code 0
```

So I can't watch the stream on the new path (/compressed/test)

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolve my problem. The image I am using `aler9/rtsp-simple-server:v0.22.2` doesn't include FFmpeg, I have to use an image that includes FFmpeg as explained in the README, like `bluenviron/mediamtx:latest-ffmpeg`